# For which integer $n$, $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$ can be a rational?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, trigonometry

When I studying the trigonometric functions, I sow that most of the values of $\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{n}\right)$ and $\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{n}\right)$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ are irrational.
How can we determine all the $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{n}\right)$ or $\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{n}\right)$ is a rational.
I don't see any approach for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Niven's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niven%27s_theorem) says that the only rational values of $\sin x$ when $x$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$ (that is, a rational number of degrees) are $0$, $\pm\frac12$ and $\pm1$.

A simple complete proof is given in a paper by Olmsted: [Rational Values of Trigonometric Functions](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2304540), *Amer. Math. Monthly* 52 (1945), no. 9, 507–508.

Comment: How can I find a proof of this theorem. Is it a difficult one?

Comment: @NilanC.Manoj, the Wikipedia page contains some references. See my edited answer.