# If $x \in \Bbb Q$, then $\cos (\pi x)$ is either irrational or in $\{0, \pm1, \pm\frac 1 2\}$

Tags: real-analysis

How can I prove that If $x \in \Bbb Q$, then $\cos (\pi x)$ is either irrational or in $\{0, \pm1, \pm\frac 1 2\}$?

Comment: For $\;x=\frac16\;$ you get $\;\frac{\sqrt3}2\;$ ...

Comment: @MorganRodgers yes, I'm trying to make trigonometric transformations, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For which integer $n$, $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$ can be a rational?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863137/for-which-integer-n-sin-left-frac-pin-right-can-be-a-rational)

Comment: @MartinR: The _answer_ to that also covers this question (but just barely, since it is a link-only answer), but the _question_ is more narrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as Niven's theorem, and a proof is publicly available on the internet, as a Google search reveals quickly. The key idea of the proof is to note that if $ x $ is rational, we can always find a monic polynomial with integer coefficients such that $ 2\cos(\pi x) $ is a root. By the rational root theorem, this forces the rational roots of the equation to be integers, and the result follows immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $x=\frac{a}{b}$ and $\cos x\pi$ is rational but not one of $0,\pm1,\pm\frac{1}{2}$. The usual formula gives $\cos a\pi=\cos bx\pi$ as a polynomial in $p(\cos x\pi)$ with integer coefficients and leading coefficient $2^{b-1}$. Suppose $\cos x\pi=\frac{c}{d}$ in lowest terms, then $$p(\frac{c}{d})=\pm1\ \ (*)$$ Hence $d$ must divide $2^{b-1}$, so it must be a power of 2 (higher than $2^1$, by assumption), and $c$ must be odd.

But now we have $\cos 2x\pi=2\cos^2x\pi-1=\frac{c^2-\frac{d^2}{2}}{\frac{d^2}{2}}$ and the denominator $\frac{d^2}{2}$ has a strictly higher power of 2. Yet the fraction also satisfies the polynomial equation $(*)$ and so its denominator also divides $2^{b-1}$. By continued doubling we reach a contradiction.